# Unknown provider: bProvider <- b

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I have an AngularJS project with Directives and Controllers. After a while i got this error when I tried to run it:

`Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: bProvider <- b`

I have googled it and could not find any obvious solution, does anyone have a clue?

Here is my directive:

```
'use strict';
 var directives = angular.module('adminUiApp.directives.upload', []);

 directives.directive('uploadDirective',['$interval', function($interval) {

    return {
       restrict: 'A',
       replace: false,
       templateUrl: 'views/upload-directive.html',
       controller: function($scope) {
       //some code
       },
       controllerAs: 'UploadCtrl'
   };

 }]);
 directives.directive('uploadFileDirective', [ '$parse', '$timeout', function($parse, $timeout) {
return function(scope, elem, attr) {
    var fn = $parse(attr['ngFileSelect']);
    elem.bind('change', function(evt) {
    });
 };
}]);
directives.directive('customPopover', function(){
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    template:'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>',
    link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
            scope.label =attrs.popoverLabel;
            $(el).popover({
                trigger: 'hover',
                html:true,
                content: attrs.popoverHtml,
                placement: attrs.popoverPlacement
            });
    }
};
});
```

Here is my app.js

```
angular
.module('adminUiApp', [
'ngAnimate',
'ngCookies',
'ngResource',
'ngRoute',
'ngSanitize',
'ngTouch',
'adminUiApp.directives.upload',
'adminUiApp.directives.navigation',
'angularFileUpload'
])
.config(['$routeProivder', function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
  })
  .when('/about', {
    templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
    controller: 'AboutCtrl'
  })
  .when('/upload', {
      templateUrl: 'views/upload.html',
      controller: 'UploadCtrl'
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });
}]);
```

Here is my controller:

```
 angular.module('adminUiApp')
 .controller('UploadCtrl', ['$scope', '$upload', '$timeout', '$http','$interval' function ($scope, $upload, $timeout, $http, $interval) {
 //Some logic
  }]);
```

**EDIT**

Here is my adminUiApp.directives.navigation.

```
var directives = angular.module('adminUiApp.directives.navigation', []);

directives.directive('navDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'views/nav-directive.html',
        controller: function($scope) {
        //some code
    },
    controllerAs: 'tab'
};
});
```

Here is my AboutCtrl:

```
angular.module('adminUiApp')
.controller('AboutCtrl',['$scope', function ($scope) {
$scope.awesomeThings = [
  'HTML5 Boilerplate',
  'AngularJS',
  'Karma'
];
}]);
```

Here is my MainCtrl:

```
angular.module('adminUiApp')
.controller('MainCtrl',['$scope', function ($scope) {
$scope.awesomeThings = [
  'HTML5 Boilerplate',
  'AngularJS',
  'Karma'
];
}]);
```

I found [this](https://coderwall.com/p/eeqo7q) proposed solution but as far as I could see I have already done that. Have I missed something here?

Edit: Code updated with Alexandre Nucera's answer, but I'm getting the same error.

**SOLVED**

For some odd reason I had to pass my $scope and $interval parameters inside the controller function in the return statement for the "uploadDirective".

```
var directives = angular.module('adminUiApp.directives.upload', []);

directives.directive('uploadDirective', function() {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: false,
        templateUrl: 'views/upload-directive.html',
        controller:['$scope', '$interval', function($scope, $interval) {
        //logic code
        }],
        controllerAs: 'uploadCtrl'
    };

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link you provided gives the right answer, you've just missed one injection dependency in your app.js :

```
config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
 ...
}]);
```

Also in your directive, use this syntax for your embedded controllers :

```
 controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
        //some code
    }]
```

**Edit** : if you find this process tedious or if you can't spot remaining issues, you can use [ngmin](https://github.com/btford/ngmin)

Also, check out the official documentation : https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05#controller_a-note-on-minification

**Edit 2** : Since you mentioned grunt in your comment I assume that you are using the uglify plugin. If you really can't find the issue, you can't still disable the mangling in your grunt file :

```
// Project configuration.
grunt.initConfig({
  uglify: {
    options: {
      mangle: false
    },
    my_target: {
      files: {
        'dest/output.min.js': ['src/input.js']
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: You are correct, but adding the injection dependency did not fix the problem, I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: You only provide a sample of your code, maybe you miss others ?

Comment: I provided my controller declaration, and that's it for dependencies declaration in my project.

Comment: I don't think that's it, in your app.js you declare a dependency with 'adminUiApp.directives.navigation' but you dont provide the code for this directive. You also have a MainCtrl, AboutCtrl

Comment: ...another thing, I just discovered that ng-min is defined in my gruntfile. So, perhaps it's not installed correctly or is not working correctly?

Comment: I don't know, do you use the ng-min task when you run grunt ? I edited my answer with another possible solution since you use grunt. I also spotted other issues in your controllers inside directives.

Comment: Ok, so after doing some of the changes you requested, I have recieved a new error, which looks more defined although I still dont get why I get the error. The new error is 'Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $uploadProvider <- $upload' Thanks for helping, Alexandre :)

Comment: Well I can't help more, you got to experiment a bit. But if you really can't find, try to disable the mangling in your Gruntfile. The minified js will be heavier but that's acceptable if its just for a small or side project.

Comment: I solved it. For some weird reason I could not pass the dependencies in the directive function, it had to be done in the controller function inside the return statement directive. I'll update the post with the code. Thanks for your help, Alexandre!