# Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider : Unknown provider: bProvider <- b

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tomcat, grails

I'm writing a webapp in AngularJS, and the backend is using Grails.

When developing the app, I am able to use `grails run-app` to test it out, but when deploying the app to a WAR file and putting it in a Tomcat server, it does not work. Here is the error (printed to JS console): http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/unpr?p0=bProvider%20%3C-%20b

You can see a live version (for a limited time) here: http://test.neonorb.com/now/JKQXV

Normally, that error would not print, and you will see websocket messages being sent (without doing anything on the page). Also, the red "Release Cars" button will not show until action was taken to request that permission.

Ignore the tabs and stuff at the top of the page, that was some test code not removed :)

The below source was taken from the generated website, not the source code:

HTML

```
<html xmlns:g="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <title>

        Derby Now

    </title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/tether.min-4186a131ed207fcfa437beada37e2c43.js" ></script>

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-vZ2WRJMwsjRMW/8U7i6PWi6AlO1L79snBrmgiDpgIWJ82z8eA5lenwvxbMV1PAh7"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/now-c4982049a08d396b941fb3f99cd2a262.css"/>

    <!--AngularJS-->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>



    <meta name="layout" content="now"/>

    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/sockjs/1.0.3/sockjs.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/stomp-ecc832be915b26d506ef5942177c9db1.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/now-a8076e472f12cc0da0dae7cef46aa98d.js" ></script>
    <script>
        initNow("/stomp", "JKQXV");
    </script>

</head>
<body ng-app="derby-now">
<div class="body">

<header class="navbar navbar-light">
    <button class="navbar-toggler hidden-sm-up" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#navbar" style="font-size: 1.8rem; color: black; height: 3rem;">
        &#9776;
    </button>

    <ul class="nav nav-tabs hidden-xs-down" id="myTab">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#one">One</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#two">Two</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="collapse hidden-sm-up" id="navbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#one">One</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#two">Two</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</header>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="one">ONE TAB</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="two">TWO TAB</div>
</div>
<script>
    $('#myTab a:first').tab('show');

    // FIXME the below code does NOT work, and needs to be replaced with the ability to bind the two views for switching panes
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
        e.target.tab('show'); // newly activated tab
        e.relatedTarget.tab('hide'); // previous active tab
    });
</script>
<div style="overflow: hidden; background-color: rgb(0, 255, 111)">
    <div style="transform: translateY(40%); height: 100%">
        <div id="content" class="container" style="transform: translateY(-50%); width: 80%; max-width: 30em">
            <p>Derby ID: JKQXV</p>
            <div ng-controller="ReleaseCarsController">
                <p>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-show="permissionReleaseCars" ng-click="releaseCars()">
                        Release Cars
                    </button>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <button class="btn btn-success" ng-hide="permissionReleaseCars"
                            ng-click="requestPermissionReleaseCars()">
                        Request Permission Release Cars
                    </button>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

/assets/now-a8076e472f12cc0da0dae7cef46aa98d.js

```
// ----- cookies -----

// sets a cookie
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}

// gets a cookie
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

// ----- utils -----

// makes a HTTP GET request async
function httpGetAsync(theUrl, callback) {
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
            callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, true); // true for asynchronous 
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}

function initNow(stomp, derbyId){
    var app = angular.module('derby-now',[]);

    // initialize websocket
    var socket = new SockJS(stomp);
    var client = Stomp.over(socket);

    // get IDs
    var clientId = getCookie('derby-now-' + derbyId);

    app.run(function($rootScope) {
        // sets the derby and client IDs in a cookie for one (1) day
        function setIdCookie() {
            setCookie('derby-now-' + derbyId, clientId, 1);
        }

        // handles websocket messages
        function messageHandler(message) {
            var event = eval('(' + message.body + ')');
            var method = event.method;

            switch(method) {
                case 'granted':
                    var permission = event.permission;

                    switch(permission){
                        case 'releaseCars':
                            $rootScope.permissionReleaseCarsGranted();
                            break;
                        default:
                            console.log("unexpected permission grant: " + permission);
                    }

                    break;
                case 'exception':
                    console.log('Server threw exception: ' + event.code);
                    break
                default:
                    console.log("unexpected method: " + method);
            }
        }

        // connects to the websocket so we can retrive messages
        function connect() {
            client.subscribe('/topic/now/' + derbyId + '/' + clientId, messageHandler);
        }

        client.connect({}, function() {
            if(clientId == "") {
                // ask the server for a client ID
                httpGetAsync('/now/' + derbyId + '/init', function(response) {
                    clientId = response;

                    // set the cookie so we can get this later
                    setIdCookie();

                    // connect to the websocket
                    connect();
                });
            } else {
                // renew cookie
                setIdCookie();

                // connect to the websocket
                connect();
            }
        });
    });

    // standard call to server
    function call(message) {
        client.send('/app/now', {}, '{' +
                '"derbyId":"' + derbyId + '",' + 
                '"clientId":"' + clientId + '",' +
                message
                + '}');
    }

    app.controller('ReleaseCarsController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope) {
        $scope.permissionReleaseCars = false;

        $rootScope.permissionReleaseCarsGranted = function() {
            $scope.$apply(function(){
                $scope.permissionReleaseCars = true;
            })
        }

        $scope.releaseCars = function() {
            call('"method":"releaseCars"');
        }

        $scope.requestPermissionReleaseCars = function() {
            call('"method":"requestPermission",' +
                 '"permission":"releaseCars"'
                );
        };
    }]);
}
```

Comment: Wonders if any googling was done pre - posting the message http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24606190/unknown-provider-bprovider-b

Answer (score 0):

Your code is minified in production, you need to change your `run` call to this:

```
app.run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
```